# Search BindingList by property

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, bindinglist

I have in my program a bindingList to which I want to add some elements. The elements are some instances of a class **NameValue_Client** which contains three properties. I want to search through the list using any property I want.

This is the class:

```
Public Class NameValue_Client
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _assigned_db_name As String, _assigned_tcp_name As String
    Private _val_obj As Client
    Private _key_obj As Integer


    Public WriteOnly Property DB_Name As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _assigned_db_name = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("DB_Name"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Value As Client
        Get
            Return _val_obj
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Client)
            _val_obj = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Key As Integer
        Get
            Return _key_obj
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _key_obj = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Key"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Name_Identifier As String
        Get
            Return String.Format("{0} : {1}", _assigned_db_name, _assigned_tcp_name)
        End Get
    End Property



    Sub New(ByVal Key As Integer, ByVal DB_Name As String)
        _assigned_db_name = DB_Name
        _key_obj = Key
    End Sub

    Private Sub changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.PropertyChanged
        If e.PropertyName = "Value" Then
            If _val_obj IsNot Nothing Then
                _assigned_tcp_name = _val_obj.Details.Computer_Name
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        If _val_obj IsNot Nothing Then
            Return String.Format("Db_Name:{0} Tcp_Name:{1} {2}", _assigned_db_name, _assigned_tcp_name, _val_obj.ToString)
        Else
            Return String.Format("Db_Name:{0} Tcp_Name:{1} Nothing", _assigned_db_name, _assigned_tcp_name)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

I found this on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/ms132695%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and it looks it's the solution but it only serches for one property and I don't want to put a select case . It has to be a better way.

This is the code I found:

```
Public Class MyFontList
    Inherits BindingList(Of Font)

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property SupportsSearchingCore() As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function FindCore(ByVal prop As PropertyDescriptor, _
        ByVal key As Object) As Integer
        ' Ignore the prop value and search by family name.<--That's why
        Dim i As Integer
        While i < Count
            If Items(i).FontFamily.Name.ToLower() = CStr(key).ToLower() Then
                Return i
            End If
            i += 1
        End While

        Return -1
    End Function
End Class
```

And I don't know how to implement this 'child' class (never worked with this type).

---

This is my code(until now):

```
Public Class NameValue_Client
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _assigned_db_name As String, _assigned_tcp_name As String
    Private _val_obj As Client
    Private _key_obj As Integer


    Public WriteOnly Property DB_Name As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _assigned_db_name = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("DB_Name"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Value As Client
        Get
            Return _val_obj
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Client)
            _val_obj = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Key As Integer
        Get
            Return _key_obj
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _key_obj = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Key"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Name_Identifier As String
        Get
            Return String.Format("{0} : {1}", _assigned_db_name, _assigned_tcp_name)
        End Get
    End Property



    Sub New(ByVal Key As Integer, ByVal DB_Name As String)
        _assigned_db_name = DB_Name
        _key_obj = Key
    End Sub

    Private Sub changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.PropertyChanged
        If e.PropertyName = "Value" Then
            If _val_obj IsNot Nothing Then
                _assigned_tcp_name = _val_obj.Details.Computer_Name
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        If _val_obj IsNot Nothing Then
            Return String.Format("Db_Name:{0} Tcp_Name:{1} {2}", _assigned_db_name, _assigned_tcp_name, _val_obj.ToString)
        Else
            Return String.Format("Db_Name:{0} Tcp_Name:{1} Nothing", _assigned_db_name, _assigned_tcp_name)
        End If
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Interface_NameValue
    Inherits BindingList(Of NameValue_Client)

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property SupportsSearchingCore() As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function FindCore(ByVal prop As PropertyDescriptor, _
        ByVal key As Object) As Integer

        ' Ignore the prop value and search by family name.
        Dim i As Integer

        While i < Count
            ''Old-fashion way
            Select Case prop.Name
                Case "Value"
                Case "Key"
                Case "Name_Identifier"
            End Select
            i += 1
        End While

        Return -1
    End Function
End Class
```

And now what am I supposed to do with this new class? How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I want to search through the list using any property I want...and I don't want to put a select case .`

The `MyFontList` class from MSDN is showing part of what you would do to implement a collection *class* - notice the `Inherits BindingList(Of Font)` - rather than modifying the *item* class (`NameValue_Client`).  Your code would them use that class in place of the `BindingList(of NameValue_Client)` collection variable.

There is an easier way.

First, though there is no reason for your item class to subscribe to its own `PropertyChanged` event.  Just change the `Value` setter to this:

```
Set(ByVal value As Client)
    _val_obj = value
    If _val_obj IsNot Nothing Then
        _assigned_tcp_name = _val_obj.ComputerName
    End If
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"))
End Set
```

Updating `_assigned_tcp_name` *before* you raise the event will allow the new value to be visible to anything subscribing to the event and perhaps using `Name_Identifier`. But you should consider getting rid of `_assigned_tcp_name` since it allows the possibility of it being "stale":

```
Public ReadOnly Property Name_Identifier As String
    Get
        Dim tcpname = If(Value IsNot Nothing, Value.ComputerName, "")
        Return String.Format("{0} : {1}", _assigned_db_name, tcpname)
    End Get
End Property
```

It also seems very odd for a `KeyValuePair` type class where the `Value` is basically optional (apparently it is manually set).  It need not even exist at all, making it possible to have a `Key` with no `Value`.

---

When it comes to searching, there is really only one property on the item class: `Key`.  The `Value` is a type which means you may want one of any number of properties on `Client`.  `DB_Name` is WriteOnly (?!), so it cannot be searched;  I guess you might search for `Name_Identifier` but that is a compound, 'artificial' property.

We can only see 1 property on `Client` so I added some for illustration purposes:

```
Public Class Client
    Public Property ComputerName As String
    Public Property Foo As String
    Public Property Bar As Int32

    Public Sub New(n As String)
        ComputerName = n
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can use linq to find whatever you want:

```
Dim Clients As New BindingList(Of NameValue_Client)

Dim c = New Client("ziggy") With {.Bar = 9, .Foo = "9"}
Dim NVC = New NameValue_Client(1, "Alpha")
NVC.Value = c
Clients.Add(NVC)

c = New Client("zoey") With {.Bar = 7, .Foo = "Q"}
NVC = New NameValue_Client(2, "Beta")  With {.Value = c}
Clients.Add(NVC)

' find a key:
NVC = Clients.FirstOrDefault(Function(q) q.Key = 1)
' find a client object:
NVC = Clients.FirstOrDefault(Function(q) q.Value Is c)
' find a client.computername:
NVC = Clients.FirstOrDefault(Function(q) q.Value.ComputerName = "Mine")
' find a client.foo value
NVC = Clients.FirstOrDefault(Function(q) q.Value.Foo = "Q")

' return is Nothing if not found:
If NVC Is Nothing Then
    ' NOT FOUND!
Else
    ' found
    Console.WriteLine(NVC.Name_Identifier)
End If
```

What you search for can be a variable, but of course searching for a Key (int) requires an int var where other properties might require a `string` or `DateTime` variable.

As noted, if what you want cannot be found, `FirstOrDefault` will be nothing.  Searching for a `Client` object as in the second example would require that `c` be the exact same object as in the list.  A different client object even with the same property values *will not match*.  If you need that, you could implement your own comparer.

Since the `Value` can be Nothing, any query involving it ought to take that into account:

```
NVC = Clients.
        FirstOrDefault(Function(q) q.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                                 q.Value.Foo = "Q")
```

Some of the code in your item class ought to also allow for that, or change it so that an item cannot be created without a `Client` object.

Comment: All in all, I would try to refactor `Client` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and add a Key or Id property so you can in effect build the NVC class into Client itself (even if some of the props added can change or are assigned